all available create-expo-app templates & versions?
what is the complete list of available templates for create-expo-app ?
when i check the --help documentation :
% npx create-expo-app --help
....
  Options
....
    -t, --template [pkg]  NPM template to use: blank, tabs, bare-minimum. Default: blank

when i run -t :
% npx create-expo-app -t    

? Choose a template: › - Use arrow-keys. Return to submit.
❯   Blank
    a minimal app as clean as an empty canvas
❯   Blank (TypeScript)
    blank app with TypeScript enabled
❯   Navigation (TypeScript)
    File-based routing with TypeScript enabled
❯   Blank (Bare)
    blank app with the native code exposed (expo prebuild)

and then there is this feature to specify versions :
% npx create-expo-app@latest --template tabs@50

is there a place that lists all available templates and versions ?

The latest ones are here: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/templates and there are ones for each SDK, e.g.: https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-50/templates

Thank you @Wodin for your comment that answers my question:

The latest ones are here:
https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/templates
and there are ones for each SDK, e.g.:
https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-50/templates
  − Wodin

